# Setting website cookies using JavaScript+HTML

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to make my website set a cookie on the clients browser/system resulting to optimise the performance of the site. I have tried to achieve that by using existing codes from the web and watching videos, but none of those techniques seem to work for me. This is my first time doing this so perhaps someone can help me resolve this issue. I'm really stuck.

```js
let cookieWindow = document.querySelector(".consent-popup");
let cookieAccept = document.querySelector(".accept");

function setCookie(key, value, days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  } else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = key + "=" + value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}


function getCookie(key) {
  var name = key + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return null;
}


function checkCookie() {
  var user = getCookie("tcc");
  if (user != "")
    setTimeout(() => {
      cookieWindow.classList.remove('hidden');
    }, 3000);
  else {
    getCookie("tcc", value, days);
    cookieWindow.classList.add('hidden');
    if (key != "" && key != null) {
      setCookie("tcc", "x", 7);
    }
  }
}

cookieAccept.onclick = function(e) {
  cookieWindow.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```html
<div class="consent-popup" id="consent-popup">
  <p class="consent-popup-info">This site requires cookies to be accepted. By continuing to browse the site you are agreeing to our use of cookie as described in our <a href="sites/terms.html" style="text-decoration:underline;">terms</a>.
    <a href="#" class="accept" id="accept"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: if u want to store certain info on the user.. does `localStorage.setItem('uniqueName', 'JSON_STRINGIFIED_DATA')` and `localStorage.getItem('uniqueName')` help?

Comment: can you give me an example how to do that? that would help alot!

Comment: im putting it in my answer.. 2-3 minutes from now

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will simply demonstrate how to store data on the user that you can pick up at any time.
You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` but I will use `localStorage` in my example (in javascript of course)

```
function setCookie(key,value,days){
  var data = {
    value: value //I dont really know what value is
    expires: new Date().getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) //I guess there's something that expires after a certain amount of days and this is the measure of that
  }
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}

let getCookie = key => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

//example usage of these functions
setCookie('pants1', 10, 5);
let pants1 = getCookie('pants1');
let currentTimeLeft = (pants1.expires - new Date().getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
alert(`the cookie 'pants1' with value ${pants1.value} expires in ${currentTimeLeft}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to store data using pure JavaScript.
The first one being to use `cookies` and the second option is to use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
To set a cookie, you need to define the functions.

```js
const cookie = {
    get: name => {
        let c = document.cookie.match(`(?:(?:^|.*; *)${name} *= *([^;]*).*$)|^.*$`)[1]
        if (c) return decodeURIComponent(c)
    },
    set: (name, value, opts = {}) => {
        /*If options contains days then we're configuring max-age*/
        if (opts.days) {
            opts['max-age'] = opts.days * 60 * 60 * 24;

            /*Deleting days from options to pass remaining opts to cookie settings*/
            delete opts.days 
        }

        /*Configuring options to cookie standard by reducing each property*/
        opts = Object.entries(opts).reduce(
            (accumulatedStr, [k, v]) => `${accumulatedStr}; ${k}=${v}`, ''
        )

        /*Finally, creating the key*/
        document.cookie = name + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + opts
    },
    delete: (name, opts) => Cookie.set(name, '', {'max-age': -1, ...opts}) 
    // path & domain must match cookie being deleted 
}
```

Simply to use this method you define the name of the cookies and how long before it lasts (in days)

```js
cookie.set('nameOfCookie', 'cookieValue', { days: 'howManyDaysTheCookieLasts' }); //Setting a cookie
cookie.get('nameOfCookie'); //Getting a value of a cookie
cookie.delete('nameOfCookie'); //Deleting a cookie
```

---

Secondly, you can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
Local storage does not expire until it is manually deleted.
An example of using localStorage is below:

```js
localStorage.setItem('name', 'value'); //Adding a new value
localStorage.getItem('name'); //Getting the value
localStorage.deleteItem('name)'; //Deleting the value
```